# Post html with dojo RadioButton

Tags: html, http-post, dojo

I have an html form with:
    `<input name="gender" dojoType="dijit.form.RadioButton" id="male" checked="checked">male`
    `<input name="gender" dojoType="dijit.form.RadioButton" id="female">female`

My problem is that when I post this form, there is always `gender=on` in post url, regardless of whether male or female is selected.
What can I do to get checked information?
And what's the difference between "selected" and "checked" with dijit.form.RadioButton?

Comment: You may set the value attribute of `<input>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
<input name="gender" dojoType="dijit.form.RadioButton" value="0" id="male"
checked="checked">
```

It may affect post information.
Hopefully , it helps you.